# Verifying pressed keys in AutoHotKey

Tags: autohotkey

I've been searching for quite a while and took a look at alot of documentation on AHK, but haven't quite found out how to do this.

So basically, anytime CTRL + another key is pressed, I want to check what the other key is. When the other key is not one of the numpad numbers, I want to only send the other key. When the key is one of the numpad numbers, I want to send CTRL and the numpad key.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: Took a look at 'Input', but didn't quite figure it out. If there's a way to detect when any key is pressed and retrieve which key it is, I could solve it. However, I am unable to find how to do this.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? What combinations of keys do you want catch exactly? E.g. `Ctrl + Shift + Numpad0`? Or `Ctrl + a + s`?

Comment: I dont really understand the downvotes. The question is clear and surely not trivial.

Answer (score 0):

I can only think of two ways. Firstly, assigning every hotkey manually.

```
loop, 255 {
    char := chr(a_index - 1)
    try {
        hotkey, ^%char%, send_key, char
    } catch e { 
        ; many keys in the ansi chart cant be assigned to a hotkey, just ignore the error
    }
}
return
send_key:
    ; A_ThisHotkey contains the pressed combination in a format like ^C. Remove the ^
    key := subStr(a_thisHotkey, 2)
    sendraw %key%
return
```

The loop iterates over all ANSI characters. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa245259(v=vs.60).aspx for a list. It is only a short form for

```
^a::send a
^b::send b
```

etc., 255 times. This approach doesn't affect space, numpad numbers (which you want), `#` and many more, and it also cannot differentiate between lowercase and uppercase letters. But maybe it'll do for you.

Secondly, using `input`. Read the doc page about it and if you still struggle, edit your question I guess. I don't know if or how this will work for key combinations